# Distinct in select query of mysql is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, distinct

I am using  **distinct** in select query of **mysql database** like this

```
$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);
$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM vendor
LEFT JOIN branches ON branches.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id
WHERE
(vendor.name LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR vendor.description LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR branches.city LIKE '%".$query."%')");
$qrow=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result);
if(empty($qrow)){
   while($qrow=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result)){

          Some Code to display result 
<?php
   }
    mysql_close();
}
    ?>
```

Problem is this, it display every result many time , It display every result as many as it fond city from branches table , (Means: if a result in vendor table has 5 cities in branches table it will display 5 time)

Comment: Use DISTINCT YOUR_COLUMN

Comment: I also use this but... same resul as I mentioned in question SELECT DISTINCT (vendor.name, vendor.description, branches.city

Comment: yes it will do. Instead of using DISTINCT, better use GROUP BY.

Comment: DISTINCT vendor.* its working well now... thanks to all and thanks to stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working. What you're returning is all the column values from both tables. so if a vendor has 5 cities, then there are 5 distinct results:

```
Vendor   City
A        London
A        New York
B        London
C        London
```

None of these rows are the same, therefore, they ARE the distinct results of the query.

Assuming you're wanting the distinct list of vendors, then you need to so something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor.*
FROM vendor
LEFT JOIN branches ON branches.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id
WHERE
(vendor.name LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR vendor.description LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR branches.city LIKE '%".$query."%')");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DISTINCT` works - but your expectations are misguided: `SELECT DISTINCT` will remove only **completely identical** tuples from the result set, and since you request `*` which means all fields from all tables, you get tuples, that difffer in the joined table.

You can resolve this by reducing your returned columns: Either name them or just use `vendor.*`